# Finding a conditional probabilty by conditioning on geometric rv

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,...$ be indepedent rv with common distribution $F(x)$ and $N$ geometric random variable with parameter $p$. $N$ is indepedent from all the $X_i$ . let $M = \max(X_1,X_2,...,X_N)$. Find $P(M \leq x \mid N > 1 ) $

#### solution sketch

We have

$$ P(M \leq x \mid N > 1 ) = \frac{P( X_1 \leq x, X_2 \leq x, ..., X_N \leq x, N > 1 ) }{P(N > 1) }$$

$$ = \frac{P(X_1 \leq x )P( X_2 \leq x, X_3 \leq x, ..., X_N \leq x, N > 1 ) }{P(N > 1) } $$
$$ = P(X_1 \leq x ) P( \max( X_2,X_3,...,X_N \leq x  \mid N > 1 ) $$

$$ = P(X_1 \leq x ) P( \max( X_1,X_2,...,X_{N-1} \leq x  \mid N > 1 ) $$

$$ = F(x) P( M \leq x ) $$

My question is: Why can we pull out $P(X_1 \leq x)$?? I mean by this reasoning, we can also do the following

$$ P(M \leq x \mid N > 1 ) = \frac{ P(X_1 \leq x) P(X_2 \leq x) ... P(X_N \leq x ) P(N > 1) }{P(N>1) } = F^n(x) $$

Also, in the equality before last one, why is it that

$$ P( \max(X_2,...,X_N) \leq x \mid N > 1) = P( \max(X_1,...,X_{N-1} ) \leq x \mid N > 1 )$$ Why can we do this ?

Comment: In your proof, how do you get that $P(max(X_1, X_2,...,X_{N-1} \leq x | N>1) = P(M \leq x)$? $P(M \leq x)$ is for the variables $X_1,...,X_n$ all being $\leq x$, whereas you only have from $X_1,...,X_{N-1}$ here.

Comment: This is the part tat I dont understand, why is that? someone gave me this answer but I dont fully see why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done directly using the law of total probability. Note that

$$  \begin{align} P(M\leq x) & = P(M\leq x|N = 1)P(N=1) + P(M\leq x | N > 1)P(N>1) \\ & = F(x)p + (1-p)P(M\leq x| N > 1)\end{align}$$

We can calculate $P(M\leq x)$ as follows using a geometric sum:

$$ \begin{align} P(M\leq x) &  = \sum_{n\geq 1} P(M\leq x|N=n)P(N=n)\\ &= \sum_{n\geq 1} F(x)^n (1-p)^{n-1} p \\ & = \frac{F(x)p}{1 - F(x)(1-p)} \end{align} $$

where $P(M\leq x | N=n) = F(x)^n$ since the $X_i$ are independent. Some quick rearranging gives $$ P(M\leq x|N>1) = \frac{F(x)^2p}{1-F(x)(1-p)} = F(x)P(M\leq x)$$

For your method : we can pull out the $P(X_1 \leq x)$ since $X_1$ is independent from $X_i$ for $i > 1$ and from $N$. We can't pull out all of the $X_i$ because how many there are depends on $N$. In the equality before last, we are just relabelling $X_i$ to $X_{i-1}$ which we are allowed to do as the $X_i$ are i.i.d. However, I'm not a hundred percent sure how to justify the last equality.